# Limit web service access to only one app

Tags: java, android

Right now I am working on a android app and I am totally new to this.

I want to make sure my web-service is only accessible via my app.

My background is PHP. In PHP I don't need to worry about anything like that, because everything runs on a server.

In case of Java and especially Android programming things are different. Even with encryption. Everybody can just open an APK and see how the web service gets accessed. So is there a way to hide or to obfuscate the access to a web service, so only my app will be able to use it?

For test purposes I didn't add any security or encryption. This is the basic call to a web server I am doing right now:

```
String url = "http://thisismyurl.com/a.php?action=get";
String result = Web.executeWeb(url);

public class Web {

    public static String executeWeb(final String url) {

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
                {
                try 
                {
                    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    String result, line = reader.readLine();
                    result = line;
                    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                        result+=line;
                    }

                    sb.append(result);
                    //System.out.println(result);       
                    //Log.i("My Response :: ", result);

                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
          });   

        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }   

}
```

How would I hide this from the prying eyes of hackers? ;-) Is that even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy client authentication using (self signed) certificates within TLS.

This kind of configuration can be enabled on most web servers and Java application servers, and you can normally also configure the web or application server in such a way that you can retrieve the certificate of the private key that the client used to authenticate itself.

Note that HTTPS uses SSL (or now TLS) before any web trafic, so you cannot program this in your application, it does require server configuration.

Check [this link](http://www.cafesoft.com/products/cams/ps/docs30/admin/ConfiguringApache2ForSSLTLSMutualAuthentication.html) on how to configure for Apache 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use your Application's ID ( like IMEI ) as parameter in your webservice call. You need to make a table in database at server side which will store all registered device. Now only these registered device can access your webservice. This is my idea, there should be other idea as well.